# Hyperlink within a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, links

I have a Google spreadsheet with many tabs.  I would like to put a link in a cell on one tab that when clicked takes me to another cell on another tab.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

I've discovered this hack, perhaps it helps:

- open the target sheet, the one you want to link to
- copy the browser URL (notice it's unique per Sheet)
- go to the other sheet and select the cell where you want to place the link
- enter the following value in the cell: `=HYPERLINK("paste here the URL copied at step 2", "enter link text here")`

Comment: This opens a new instance of the spreadsheet -- does not just move to the selected tab.

Comment: Have you verified that? That only happens when you click the big **+** on the bottom left, isn't?

Comment: @GregSchmidt yes, you are right. I see no way of avoiding that; all links in the spreadsheet open in another tab.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra The question assumes that there are multiple tabs already ("*I have a Google spreadsheet with many tabs*").

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: Adding a new sheet with the "+" on the bottom left or clicking on an existing tab in the lower part of the Sheet shows that new/existing sheet in the *same browser window or tab*. The behavior of the HYPERLINK function, however, opens a *new browser window or tab*; rather than changing the view in the current browser window/tab.

Answer (score 2):

As of 13 February 2017, support for anchor links will be introduced:

### Link to cell ranges in Google Sheets

2/13/2017

> Because it can be difficult to navigate large and complex
>   spreadsheets, we’re introducing the ability to link to specific cell
>   ranges in Google Sheets on the web. With this new functionality, you
>   can create a “table of contents” for your spreadsheet, direct others
>   to specific content within your spreadsheet, and retain links to cells
>   when you import spreadsheets from other applications. To link to cells
>   in your spreadsheet, simply go to "Insert link" > "Select a range of
>   cells to link" and type or highlight the desired range. For more
>   details, visit the [Help Center](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893).

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

Gradual rollout (potentially longer than 3 days for feature visibility)

### Reference

Blog post reference: **[Anchor Links](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/02/link-to-cell-ranges-in-google-sheets.html)**

Answer (score 2):

1. Right Click on target cell and choose 'Get link to this cell'.
2. Add hyperlink to cell that you want to point to cell in #1. Paste in url from #1.